# Let $\log$ be a branch of the logarithm in $D$ such that $\log e=1$. Find $\log e^{15}.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms, branch-cuts, branch-points

Let $D\subset\Bbb C$ be the complement of the closed spiral $\{e^{\theta+i\theta}:\, \theta\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{ 0\}$. Let $\log$ be a branch of the logarithm in $D$ such that $\log e=1$. Find $\log e^{15}.$

I am always confused in these type of logical concept because what I am feeling that no branch can exist as $D$ is region around zero. So the argument function will be discontinuous. But there is a catch that the spiral is dense at zero, so possibly we are not getting a region around zero. Basically if I just see on a naked eye then the value should be $15$. How to write the answer with proper logic.

I saw one related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2807983/branch-of-logarithm-and-spiral) but got no answers and even the try was hard to understand.

A few notes about a branch of the logarithm  first:

A branch of the logarithm is a continuous function $L$ defined on a simply connected domain $D$ such that $e^{L(z)} = z$ for all $z$.

Since $e^z \neq 0$ for all $ z$ we cannot have $0 \in D$.

We have that $e^z = e^w$ **iff** $z=w+2\pi n i$ for some $n$.

If $L_1,L_2$ are two branches of the logarithm defined on $D$, then
we must have $L_1(z) = L_2(z) + 2 \pi n_z i$, and since $L_k$ are continuous,
we must have $L_1(z) = L_2(z) + 2 \pi n i$ for some **fixed** $n$ and for
all $z \in D$.

Please help from here!

Comment: every time you cross the spiral going on the positive axis from $e$ to $e^{15}$ you add a $2\pi i$ (since the crossing is from down to up - draw a picture and see how you get from $e$ within the spiral to say $e^{2\pi}+1$) to the argument of $\log x, x.1, x \ne e^{2k\pi}$ say; so you get that $\log e^{15}=15+2k\pi i$ where $k$ is how many times you cross the spiral; can you finish?

Comment: Yeah I think it will $15+4i\pi$ as I crossed it twice at $e^{2\pi+i2\pi}$ and $e^{4\pi+i4\pi}$. But will you explain these branch with an approach. If you know of some good video lectures on branch cuts or lecture notes. Please mention me otherwise I was thinking if we close a surface around around zero then branch can not be defined. It is true in some sense but it has some underlying understanding that I miss.

Comment: If you fix a point not on the spiral (and not zero) you can join $e$ with it by a path and continue the logarithm on the path; since branches of the logarithm  are discrete and any two such paths are homotopic, it follows that if you fix a branch of the logarithm  (equivalently the argument of $\log e$ which  here is chosen zero) the continuation is path independent; this is how i think of this issue; then it's  a matter of tracing the arguments and they jump only at crossings with the real axis (drawing a picture helps)